# Python function or nested loop that does a distance calculation for each unique item in column

Tags: python, loops, nested, distance, nested-loops

Basically lets say I have 3 cars and a bunch of x/y coordinates as below:

car number  ___   x coor    ___     y coor
1        _____________    54          _____    25
1      _____________      57  _____     26
1      _____________      54  _____    29
2  _____________      52           _____   24
2  _____________  56  _____           28
2  _____________ 57        _____   29
3          _____________  51   _____  25
3        _____________    54   _____  26
3     _____________       59     _____         29

What I need my code to do is to calculate displacement or distance traveled for each car from the coordinates, with output showing something like

car __  displacement
1    ________      9
2    ________      5
3    ________      7

What I have currently is below and definitely doesn't work

```
displacement  = 0
for (car number, x coor, y coor) in coorset:
    for i in car number:
        displacement(i) = displacement  + (df[coor x] **2 + df[coor y] **2)**.5
        print (displacement)
        print(car number)
```

I'm new to python so forgive my mistakes, I'm just really confused.

Comment: Are you using a dataframe to store these values?

Comment: @Ozzy08 Yep! I should have mentioned that, but yeah I am using a dataframe.

Comment: I was able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

# create data
data = DataFrame([
    (1, 54, 25),
    (1, 57, 26),
    (1, 54, 29),
    (2, 52, 24),
    (2, 56, 28),
    (2, 57, 29),
    (3, 51, 25),
    (3, 54, 26),
    (3, 59, 29),
], columns=['car_number', 'x_coord', 'y_coord'])


# calculate distances
data['distance'] = (
    (data['x_coord'] - data['x_coord'].shift()) ** 2 +
    (data['y_coord'] - data['y_coord'].shift()) ** 2
) ** 0.5

# ignore distances between points for different cars
data['same_car'] = data['car_number'] == data['car_number'].shift()
data['distance'] = data['distance'] * data['same_car']

# group distances by car and sum
distances = data.groupby('car_number')['distance'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I took a slice of the dataframe corresponding to the current car number, modified it to include the displacements, and then replaced it in the original dataframe.

```
data["displacement"] = 0

def distance_x(df, i):
        return (df.iloc[i, 1] - df.iloc[i + 1, 1]) ** 2

def distance_y(df, i):
    return (df.iloc[i, 2] - df.iloc[i + 1, 2]) ** 2

def total_displacement(df):
    cars = df["car_number"].unique()
    for car_num in cars:
        df_sel = df[df["car_number"] == car_num].copy()
        for i in range(len(df_sel) - 1):
            distance = (distance_x(df_sel, i) + distance_y(df_sel, i)) ** (1/2)
            df_sel.iloc[i + 1, 3] = distance + df_sel.iloc[i, 3]
        df[df["car_number"] == df_sel.iloc[0,0]] = df_sel    
    return df
    
total_displacement(data)
print(data)

 car_number  x_coord  y_coord  displacement
0         1.0     54.0     25.0      0.000000
1         1.0     57.0     26.0      3.162278
2         1.0     54.0     29.0      7.404918
3         2.0     52.0     24.0      0.000000
4         2.0     56.0     28.0      5.656854
5         2.0     57.0     29.0      7.071068
6         3.0     51.0     25.0      0.000000
7         3.0     54.0     26.0      3.162278
8         3.0     59.0     29.0      8.993230
```